# Styling separate arrays of words in mark.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a list of words that I'm using, one list is a good list, one a bad list, and one a neutral list. I've been highlighting the good list with mark.js and styling it green with the .css method. If I highlight the bad list and the neutral list, it would also turn green. Is there a way that I can color the bad one red, good one green, and neutral grey?

```
   var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("#postingbody"));
instance.mark(positive, {
           accuracy: "exactly",
           separateWordSearch: false
});
 var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("#postingbody"));
instance.mark(bad, {
           accuracy: "exactly",
           separateWordSearch: false
});
  var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("#postingbody"));
instance.mark(neutral, {
           accuracy: "exactly",
           separateWordSearch: false
});
```

The code adds a  to all words it highlights, so right now the code that I use to highlight it is:

```
$('mark').css({'background':'transparent' , 'color':'red'});
```

And the text I want to highlight would just be:

```
<div id = "postingbody">
hey I'm some text I wanna highlight
</div>
```

Comment: can u show some code in html, and css which highlighting this lists?

Comment: @MaciejWójcik Yep, just added the code! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your mark() method parameters you can specify a CSS class name like in the code below:

```
instance.mark(positive, {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false,
    className: "green"
});
```

You can create your CSS class like this:

```
.green {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  background: transparent;
}
```